# Rotated triangles change their center HTML5

Tags: html, canvas

I have a problem with my program. I wanted to rotate triangle few times and draw it every time I rotate, but triangle changes it's place( I wanted it on the center of the screen).
The triangle drawing is in draw function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var ctx, canvas;



        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
            return (window.requestAnimationFrame || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame) &&
            function(callback) {
              window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/1 );
            };
      })();

            window.onload = function(){
                canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                //sciana

                for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){

                    drawLine(i);
                }

            }
            function drawLine(a){
            var bok = 400, xw = canvas.width/2, yw = 10, odstep = 10;
            var tX = 10/Math.sqrt(3);
                ctx.rotate(Math.PI /6); //here I rotate
                ctx.save();


                for(var i = xw; i >= xw - bok/2; i-=tX){
                    var r = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var g = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var b = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());   
                    ctx.translate(10/Math.sqrt(3), 10);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                    ctx.arc(xw, 0, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.closePath();

                }   
                ctx.restore(); 
                ctx.save();
                    for(var i = xw; i >= xw - bok/2; i-=10/Math.sqrt(3)){
                    var r = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var g = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var b = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());   
                    ctx.translate(-10/Math.sqrt(3), 10);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                    ctx.arc(xw, 0, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.closePath();
                }   
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.save();
                xw = xw - bok/2 ;
                yw = bok*Math.sqrt(3)/2;
                for(var i = xw; i <= xw + bok; i+=10){
                    var r = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var g = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());
                    var b = Math.floor( 255 * Math.random());   
                    ctx.translate(10,0);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                    ctx.arc(xw, yw, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fill(); 
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
                ctx.restore();
                requestAnimFrame(drawLine); 

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color:#D0D0D0">
            Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje elementu Canvas.
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know about how it rotates around the center of the canvas so you have to translate the center of your triangle to that before rotating it and then translate it back after?

Comment: @Delta could you give me an example?

Comment: Suppose you have an equilateral triangle which side's length is 10. The height of that triangle is `Math.sqrt(200)`, so the center is located at `(5, Math.sqrt(200) / 2)`. You're drawing it in the center of the canvas so in order to translate it to the origin you just `ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2-5, -canvas.height/2-Math.sqrt(200)/2)` then rotate, and then, apply the inverse translation.